# PCRE regex to remove space before dot, and add one after it, but also not affect ellipsis

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I'm not very keen on regex, I only have some intermediate knowledge on the matter just to help me deal with everyday PHP programming. But this problem I faced is beyond my current knowledge.

I created a regex pattern to find any characters in the format of `word      .Word` and replace it with `word. Word`

The regex it this `[ \t]*\.[ \t]*` and the replacement it `'. '`

However, I just noticed that the above turns ellipsis three dots (...) into . . .

I think this can be solved with positive (or negative) lookahead (or lookbehind) but I haven't worked with those ever, and although I experimented a little bit, I couldn't find the right combination to exclude the ellipsis' three dots from getting matched by my regex.

Any help would be much appreciated, esp. if you could add to my current regex the correct missing part to cover the ellipsis case, instead of suggesting a totally different one. TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
(?:[ \t]+\.[ \t]*)|(?:[ \t]*\.[ \t]+)|(?<=\w)\.(?=\w)
```

with `'. '` as substitution

[**demo**](https://regex101.com/r/MCP1OZ/1/)

**Input:**

```
word      .Word #case 1
word...        #case 2 (nothing should be done here)
word      .     Word #case3
word.   Word #case 4
word.Word #case5
```

**Output:**

```
word. Word
word...
word. Word
word. Word
word. Word
```

**Explanations:**

- With your current regex the `...` ends up being processed and a space is added after each `.`, We thus have to add some constraints to avoid it.
- `(?:[ \t]+\.[ \t]*)` will process cases `#1` and `#3` (enforce the constraint that you have at least a space or a tab before the dot)
- `(?:[ \t]*\.[ \t]+)` will process cases `#4` and `#3` (enforce the constraint that you have at least a space or a tab after the dot)
- the remaining case `#5` will be met by `(?<=\w)\.(?=\w)` where you add the lookbehind/lookahead constraint (on the characters surrounding the `.`) to avoid matching `...`

Let me know if this is clear and if it works for you! Cheers.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: Thank you buddy! In very short, Regex can be learned completely independently and as a whole. The starting point would be to learn about `Finite State Machine`,`DFA`, `NFA` to understand the whole principles behind the regex. Even if an important part of the regex syntax does not change between each programming languages, 
some modes, and features are available in only some regex engines. 
The syntax might also differ a lot between for example the POSIX `basic` and extended regex.
So in the end, you will need to learn how to use the regex for a specific context

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: (regex syntax, modes that are allowed, and also the specific language libraries that allow you to create a pattern, use backreference,...)
this website is a good starting point: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html

Comment: Now this one!!! Well this is 1000% what I needed. An extension of my regex with the needed group constructs (I really need to study those lookahead's and lookbehind's). And because you didn't use any parentheses, I can do a simple replace, without having to use $1 etc... Thanks a million my friend!

Comment: Ah, I just noticed that your regex, as is, doesn't work very well in my situation to address #case5. And that's because I use Greek text as well, and \w doesn't recognize Greek characters as word characters unless /u (unicode) flag is also selected.

Comment: @Peter K. I can fix that point when I have access to a PC you can replace `\w` by `\uXxx` but I would recommend to use `\p{L}` to accept any language letter check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50576961/regex-for-first-name-only-english/50577077#50577077

Comment: No, it's OK, like I said, I added the unicode flag and it solved the problem. I mentioned it, just so that others who read this thread in the future will have that in mind before they decide that your solution doesn't help their situation. Thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 1):

This extension to your regex will do what you want. It looks for a single period between word boundaries (`\b`), regardless of spacing (`[ \t]*`) and replaces it with a single period and space. The positive lookahead for `(\b|\R|$)` at the end allows it to match the last word in a line as well. Addition of the `u` modifier allows it to work with e.g. Greek text too.

```
\b[ \t]*\.[ \t]*(?=\b|\R|$)
```

replace with

```
'. '
```

Example:

```
$lorem = 'Λορεμ ιπσθμ .  δολορ σιτ αμετ, διcτασ
ινcιδεριντ σεα cθ.   Ρεqθε οφφενδιτ προβατθσ.    ει
δθο, ατ σιντ μοδθσ σεα    .Cθ qθανδο σθσcιπιτ 
εφφιcιαντθρ vιμ, αν.νονθμεσ οφφιcιισ περcιπιτθρ
ηισ. Ναμ εξερcι πθτεντ . ερθδιτι ιδ, αδ
qθαεqθε γραεcισ cονσεcτετθερ νεc, 
cθ ναμ σολθμ φαcερ cοτιδιεqθε   .    Στετ 
ινvενιρε περ νο, qθο αδ λεγερε δελενιτ αδιπισcινγ   .

The quick brown.fox jumps over   .  the lazy.   dog   . twice  .  ';

echo preg_replace('/\b[ \t]*\.[ \t]*(?=\b|\R|$)/u', '. ', $lorem);
```

Output:

```
Λορεμ ιπσθμ. δολορ σιτ αμετ, διcτασ
ινcιδεριντ σεα cθ. Ρεqθε οφφενδιτ προβατθσ. ει
δθο, ατ σιντ μοδθσ σεα. Cθ qθανδο σθσcιπιτ 
εφφιcιαντθρ vιμ, αν. νονθμεσ οφφιcιισ περcιπιτθρ
ηισ. Ναμ εξερcι πθτεντ. ερθδιτι ιδ, αδ
qθαεqθε γραεcισ cονσεcτετθερ νεc, 
cθ ναμ σολθμ φαcερ cοτιδιεqθε. Στετ 
ινvενιρε περ νο, qθο αδ λεγερε δελενιτ αδιπισcινγ.

The quick brown. fox jumps over. the lazy. dog. twice.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Technically, it solves my problem, which was a regex to handle the dots effectively but at the same time exclude the ellipsis from the matches. However, as I initially stated, I wanted an answer that would extend my regex instead of introducing a new one. What’s more, your answer (using parentheses) matches the last character before the dot, and the first after it, so I have to use match[2] results to do the replaces. Having said all the above, and although I marked it as a useful answer (technically it is anyway), I cannot mark it as the solution to my problem.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for the upvote. I apologise for not reading your question thoroughly and missing the part about extending your existing expression. I've edited my answer with something which does solve the problem as asked and will also work with greek characters with the addition of the `u` modifier.

Comment: I always knew that stackoverflow users had such a great amount of knowledge to share! What I didn't know was that they are also so kind persons as well! Thank you very much Nick! This indeed is a great solution to my problem. Compact, extends my own regex, and doesn't introduce new capture group with extra parentheses etc...

Comment: Thank you for the kind words. I use this site to find answers myself - it's so good I haven't had to ask a new question yet - and am always happy to give back. Plus I love the challenge and often learn something new from answering other people's questions.