# Regex for First name only English

Tags: regex

I need to define a regex for First name, the requirement is below.

- no numeric or special characters only alphabets allowed
- should not start with space
- spaces allowed after 1st char
- min length is 1 and max 8

For the above I am using `/^\S[a-zA-Z\s]{1,8}/`

Somehow, it's allowing special characters in first char.

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: which programming language?

Comment: So is a string like "x" followed by 7 spaces also accepted? And what about other whitespaces than space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]{0,7}$
```

[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/C3wBy0/3/)

**Explanations:**

- `^` beginning of line anchor
- `[a-zA-Z]` first character is only a letter
- `[a-zA-Z ]{0,7}` the rest of the string can be upper case or lower case letter repeated 1 to 7 times to implement your length constraint.
- `$` anchor for EOL constraint

**DISCLAIMER:**

This regex works fine for English names, but will reject all names in which you have Latin/Japanese/... characters.

For a **more general regex** that accepts more international names:

```
^\p{L}(?:\p{L}| |　){0,7}$
```

You can use this one allowing both normal and Japanese spaces.

[**DEMO 2**](https://regex101.com/r/C3wBy0/2/)

Answer (score 1):

`\S` matches any non-whitespace character (equal to `[^\r\n\t\f\v ]`).

I am no regex ninja, but this should work: `^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z ]{0,7}`. See: https://regex101.com/r/xQe81c/4

Comment: `\S` also disallows lots of things in Unicode. Should be equivalent to `\P{Z}`, I think.

Comment: You do not need to specify `{1}` ;-)

Comment: @Allan Thank you. Updated.

Comment: Anyway nice answer +1 ;-)

Comment: Why not ending with $ ?

Answer (score 1):

This should work: `^[a-zA-z][a-zA-Z\s]{1,7}$`

Comment: Why A-z? Is that a typo? Btw, this won't match minimum 1.